# D3 js Drag and Drop Zoomable Tree help in collapsing nodes connected by a certain link

Tags: d3.js, tree

I am new to D3.js I have followed example [Drag and Drop Zoomable Tree](http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/). I want to modify its functionality in such a way that instead of collapsing and expanding of tree on clicking of nodes, I want to achieve this functionality on click of a link. I don't know how to do it. Please help me in this regard as I am unable in understanding of javascript code. I have just copied the code from example and had used it.

Comment: Well what have you tried? What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: link means a connection line that connects two nodes in a tree. I have integrated the example that is given in link in first line of my question. Now I want to modify that code in order to achieve my goal. I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 2):

OK to answer what I think your question is,

You need to add a click function for the link (and perhaps remove the click function for the nodes themselves).

Javascript:

```
function clickLink(d) {
        d = d.target;
        d = toggleChildren(d);
        update(d);
        centerNode(d);
    }
```

Then you need to modify the link `enter` method and chain the click listener to it.
Javascript:

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {
                    x: source.x0,
                    y: source.y0
                };
                return diagonal({
                    source: o,
                    target: o
                });
            })
            .on('click', clickLink); // <--- Add this part.
```

Then optionally you can make the CSS make the links seem `clickable` by adding
CSS:

```
.node, .link {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Optionally you may want to give your users a bigger target to click so you can increase the `stroke-width` value to something bigger like this
CSS:

```
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
```

Demo here http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/0f29a2c867dcb1b44d18 based on this Gist https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/0f29a2c867dcb1b44d18

P.S. You could have always asked at my blog :)